# Welcome Redditors?

Tags: discussion

Okay I was just surfing Stack Overflow, and [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21186724/why-is-whitespace-sometimes-needed-around-metacharacters). In that, a message is displayed:

> Welcome, Redditors! We're looking for answers that provide serious,
>   practical solutions to the problem stated. If you'd prefer to post a
>   joke or launch a tangential discussion, please do so on the
>   corresponding Reddit thread.

I’ve never seen this before. How many such unknown messages are there in Stack Overflow and what are they?

Comment: They're only unknown if you don't know about them... To answer correctly, someone must know what you know.

Comment: *I've **never** seen this before* @Ben

Comment: Where's that message? Cannot reproduce...

Comment: [If anyone wants to know, this is what it looked like.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o2c7r.png)

Comment: It was removed. It's just a post notice; there is nothing special about these things and they are easily visible in the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21186724/revisions) along with close/reopen notices, protections, and bounty notices. I'm more surprised the post notice remained around after so many months.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Post Notices can be added to a post by moderators. These are predefined. Moderators cannot add their own text. Post Notices appear below the posts until removed manually.

Currently, Stack Overflow moderators can pick the following:

- **citation needed**: This post does not cite any references or sources. Please help improve this post by adding citations to reliable sources. Unsourced material may be challenged and removed.
- **current event**: Post is related to a rapidly changing event.
- **insufficient explanation**: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.
- **redditted**: Welcome, Redditors! We're looking for answers that provide serious, practical solutions to the problem stated. If you'd prefer to post a joke or launch a tangential discussion, please do so on the corresponding Reddit thread.

This is how it looks like in the UI:

[image: post notices]

Related information on meta.SE:

- [What are these notices above my post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post)
- [How rare should post notices be?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172571/how-rare-should-post-notices-be)
- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/

As for the reddited one:

The **reddited** post notice came into existence after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415881/how-to-pair-socks-from-a-pile-efficiently) somehow made it to the [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/16x9a3/how_to_pair_socks_from_a_pile_efficiently/?sort=old) frontpage. It resulted in lots and lots of joke answers and comments on that question, which we deleted, which then created complaints on MSO. So [@shog9 added the notice](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/16y0as/til_that_redditors_going_to_stack_overflow_and/c80j92e) to handle this:

> I created that notice for a question earlier today. I did so after deleting a half-dozen or so "answers" that, while perhaps somewhat clever, didn't bother trying to actually answer the question.

Comment: When do you use those? Where a comment doesn't fit (or isn't prominent enough), and you cannot just lock the question?

Comment: @Bergi to be honest, most of the time I don't use them at all. They are [somewhat of a hassle to keep track of](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184866). But yes, the idea is when a comment wouldn't be prominent enough (e.g. too many comments already).

Comment: I feel like such a policy unfairly singles out Redditors. Not all Redditors are jokesters and not all jokesters are Redditors.

Comment: It's not a "policy", @Pieter - there was actually a big crowd of people showing up from Reddit and posting jokes as answers, then complaining loudly about censorship on meta. The notice *helped*. It's not something we have to use very often.

Comment: @Shog9: I don't doubt that this particular incident was Reddit-related and in that specific case such a notice is justified. But this general "no joke answers" notice that mods can put up on any question specifically mentions Reddit, which may not always be the source of the joke answers.

Comment: Huh, I always thought that banner was generated automatically when the HTTP referrer contained `reddit.com`.

Answer (score 13):

By definition, there are no unknown messages in existence.

A moderator can create a custom post notice and then afix it. There is currently no way to afix a purely arbitrary message in that fashion - it must be selected from a list. Therefore it cannot be unknown unless it hasn't been created yet.

What you are actually asking is: *what post notice options do the moderators have?*.

Comment: Its funny that they *welcome* redittors and ask them to leave in a decent manner :)

Comment: Is the "redditted" notice available on your site? If not, it's probably unique to SO. Other than that there's just the three standard ones I know of.

Comment: Reddited is not available on my section of the SE network, nor am I allowed to make custom post notices. Are both these features available on SO proper?

Comment: @jmac the reddited one was prompted by an incident on SO, so it might be available to SO only. See my edit please.

Answer (score -5):

[Google says there is only one](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20%22welcome%2C%20redditors!%22).

I strongly suspect it was written manually by a moderator, after seeing unusually high chatty behaviour and noting that it was predominantly due to a post on Reddit.

Comment: I'm not talking of number of that messages. I'm talking about how many such unknown messages are there :)

Comment: @AmitJoki: I think you'd have to present a better definition of "unknown messages". If you're asking how many there _could_ be then, well, if it's freehand text from a moderator the answer is "near-infinite". Why do you care?

Comment: @AD7six: It's certainly not based on referrer information, since I can see it right now and have never been on Reddit. It's also definitely not as simple as "lots of traffic" because (a) that would be a non sequitur, and (b) there are hundreds of hyper-visited questions that, as I've already shown, do not have this message. Moderators are _definitely_ able to write custom messages that do not go in the question body, so I'm pretty sure that this is one of those times.

Comment: I find it amusing that this question is now Google's top result on the search you posted.

Comment: @jpmc26: And, apparently, the second! Bizarre.