# Anything wrong with spreading links?

Tags: discussion

EDIT: To all who have chimed in, thanks a lot. I really appreciate it. However, I still am confused about how it was seen as vote manipulation, as there is a voting barrier for new users (15 rep) and anyone that is able to vote due to association bonuses would already be familiar with the spirit of stack exchange sites. So, perhaps I could use a bit of clarification on that still - but thanks for answering the other questions.

I'd like to start off by saying this is by no means an attempt to appeal/argue with/undermine the decisions of the community - I just want to become a better user of this community.

Recently, I posted a feature request in meta (no link, as I don't want this to be seen as an attempt to manipulate votes) about, in gist, allowing cryptocurrency tipping. I also tried to share the link to gather feedback and ideas in another online community - and people got quite upset over it.

I always thought that sharing links was cool, as all unanswered posts have the text

> Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook.

at the bottom of the page, every post has a share link, and there are [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/260/announcer) that are granted as incentive to share. So, in order to get more feedback and ideas, I shared a link to this feature proposal on several cryptocurrency related subreddits with titles like

> "Programmer Litecoiners: Please check out my proposal to integrate
>   litecoin tipping with Stack Overflow, the Q and A site of programmers
>   worldwide".

Soon, I began getting comments like

> It should be noted that this meta question was linked in large online communities supporting this idea in an attempt to have a disproportionally large portion of proponents vote on it. In my humble opinion, this is very dubious and casts a large shadow of doubt on the proposer's claims that they are "not trying to peddle anything" and that the improvement of SE is at the core of their idea.

I wasn't trying to peddle anything, and it was just a (looking back, rather terrible) idea, and I don't have a problem with people not liking it. However, I am a bit confused as to why there was a huge issue with me sharing the link.

It absolutely wasn't to game votes, and as users must have 15 rep to be on meta, it seems unlikely that it would lead to people not familiar with SO creating accounts to upvote.

What surprised me was the assumption that I was vote rigging- as there is a 15 rep barrier to voting, the only people who could vote on it would be people who had sufficient rep, people familiar with SO and its rules/spirit.

However, what happened happened - can anyone help me figure out what I did? Am I missing something? Thanks, and again: just asking for help to become a better user, not trying to blame anyone.

Comment: If you weren't meant to share links, there wouldn't be a "share" link on every post. Enough said.

Comment: There's nothing *per se* *wrong* with it... but it looks strange considering you're linking a post for Stack Overflow users to a bunch of non-Stack Overflow users. If you wanted feedback from everyone, there's [chat] & other features of this site.

Comment: Reddit has historically drawn a lot of votes, and it can be nasty sometimes,  [There's a specific message](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258828/welcome-redditors) which moderators can add to questions getting a lot of attention from Reddit.

Comment: @hichris123 it was not to a bunch of non stackers, as far as I know - it was specifically targeted towards programmers, and meta requires a bit of rep to use, so all potential people influenced by it would have to be SO users, too.

Comment: I saw your original feature request, and read through many of the comments that ensued, including the one you mentioned. I thought it was a bit unfair, considering that we're encouraged in several different ways to share links. There is a barrier to voting on Meta, and all SE sites, and sharing the link would hopefully just increase the breadth of discussion about the topic. I think the original commenter was just feeling sore that many votes disagreed with his/hers at that point, but I wouldn't take it personally. You did the right thing.

Answer (score 13):

There's nothing wrong with raising visibility of the discussion, but the perception is that you were soliciting votes for your proposal... a negative reaction to that is perfectly understandable.

If what you wanted was feedback, your links should have indicated that.  Instead of

> Check out my proposal.

try

> Do you see anything wrong with my proposal or that could be improved?

In fact, if you have edit privileges to those external links, I'd suggest that you make the desire for feedback explicit.

Comment: I think it depends on what audience is reached. If those are litecoin  aficionados, they are likely to vote *yes* (if they have an account) not because the proposal is great, but because litecoins are great. In that case "Do you see anything wrong with my proposal or that could be improved?" is spot on. Otherwise, if the audience is expected to be diverse, "Check out my proposal." is already neutral enough.

Comment: I just am confused on how it could be seen as soliciting votes - due to the 15 rep barrier to voting on meta, it seems like the only people voting on it could be people familiar with the SO community and its rules. I thought the only thing it would do would be to add breadth. Am I missing something?

Comment: @rocket101: That 15 rep requirement is not much of a barrier, especially after association bonus is considered.  Someone slightly active on BitCoin stackexchange, who has never even visited SO before, would be able to vote.

Comment: @rocket101: Another point is that, given that it took only a couple hours to convince you the idea was terrible, you clearly went advertising your proposal way too early.  Next time, get feedback from the metazens first for 12 hours or a day, then you can invite other feedback.

Comment: @BenVoigt and yet, BTC SE has the same basic rules and spirit as any other SE site, like SO - wouldn't they be familiar with the communities' principals?

Comment: @BenVoigt as for the other point- point taken and will do in future. Thanks.