# Should I add "NO ANSWER YET" to title?

Tags: discussion, rollbacks

Quick question here - I have [a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281281/anything-wrong-with-spreading-links/) I posted on meta recently. I got a great answer I appreciate, however, it does not answer all parts of my question. I tried to:

1. Clarify with the answerer through comments. They didn't respond.
2. Not mark the answer as accepted
3. Edit the question to state that I still had questions.
4. Edit the title to

> NO ANSWER YET Anything wrong...

1-3 were unsuccessful, but edit 4 was rolled back by a community member. Looking at [How to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), I can't seem to find anything against it - what's the rule here? Was what I did an acceptable/advisable/good edit? Or are there better ways?

Comment: No you shouldn't, we can clearly see, which questions have answers or not. If you refer that questions could have been answered in comment (thus we cannot see), well, comments aren't answers.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ OK. Do you have any other suggestions to get an answer, or just wait? Thanks!

Comment: Improve your question (which will bump it up in the _active questions queue_), and yes be patient. Also you can attract more attention to your question, rewarding a bounty. (BTW, you have an answer there. May be you should clarify why this doesn't fit your concerns)

Comment: If "it does not answer all parts of my question" then that is an indication that you asked more than one thing. You can split that out into separate questions as long as it doesn't invalidate existing answers. But the part you appear to feel is unanswered may well not go down very well as a suitable question for meta anyway.

Comment: It's worth noting guys that the question in question (see what I did there...) is a Meta question, and can therefore not have a bounty.

Answer (score 26):

No please absolutely do not add something like `NO ANSWER YET` to the question title. Just as adding tags to the title is discouraged, and adding `[SOLVED]` to the title instead of accepting an answer is discouraged, placing text in the title to beg for additional views is discouraged and will very likely result in some downvotes while certainly resulting in the edit being rolled back.

A substantial edit to the question will place it back into the "Active" list where others will see it. This may be appropriate if it wasn't clear enough to receive adequate answers at first.

However, if it still hasn't gotten enough attention or a satisfactory answer, that is what the bounty system is for. Once eligible (after two days), open a bounty on the question which will place it in the "Featured" tab where it will  be seen by more eyes.

Comment: As for the text in the post, that was not to beg for views - it was to make it clear the answer was not complete, so that people wouldn't think that "It's not worth answering - it already has one". Oh, and how do I put bounty on a meta post? Thanks though, and +1!

Comment: @rocket101 - You can't put a bounty on a meta post.