# What is this new DEV share button integrated with SO?

Tags: support, sharing

I was surprised to find a link to an unknown site called DEV embedded within the share popup. It seems to be a site called dev which "requires" social login credentials to use. I'm a bit concerned about this appearing without any prior announcement. Is this an official partnership with SO, or something more sinister? If official, why aren't the SO login credentials acceptable?

[image: Share - DEV]

Comment: What is dev: https://dev.to/about

Comment: cross site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332816/158100

Comment: @rene: Why is that on MSE in the first place when it's specific to SO???

Comment: FWIW, it's similar with the existing "direct sharing to Facebook/Twitter" buttons (that somehow doesn't appear on your screenshot) that doesn't accept SO/SE credential either...

Comment: @BoltClock  not my fault users want to and can  collect rep there ;)

Comment: @yivi I read that and still wasn't any clear about what they are up to given that it demanded credentials before displaying any content

Comment: @AndrewT. I have precautions to avoid social media links. I wasn't aware these were included either.

Comment: @Script47: OK, it's definitely caching.

Comment: [I knew this site sounded familiar...](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/01/podcast-107-just-trying-non-terrible/)

Comment: @Script47 The featured Meta posts are *heavily* cached. It can take several hours for changed to work their way through. The umber of posts which can effectively be featured depends on the number of slots in the "Featured on Meta" section of the sidebar which have been used up by blog entries and posts featured on [meta.se]. Four posts featured on MSO can be displayed, and currently are.

Comment: In my opinion, this is just another one of those "Okay...? Why are you doing this?" Type moves from SO. Do they do any kind of behavior study or market analysis before making these changes?

Comment: Someone told me that if there are too many featured questions, the site will keep rotating them around when you reload. So it might look like caching. Not sure how credible a source I got that from though, since I don't remember who it was...

Comment: @BoltClock a lot of discussion re featuring posts here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387602/creating-a-system-for-featuring-posts-tell-the-mods-what-you-want. There's a limit of slots and they are also taken up by blog posts. They do rotate and are heavily cached by several different systems. Got that from Shog

Comment: Amusing that their Advertisement policy is now better and more privacy focused than that of Stack Overflow (http://dev.to/sponsorship-info)

Comment: Just looks like a dumping ground for business plugs/biased opinions to me. Perfect place for announcements!

Answer (score 88):

For whatever reason, this was only [announced on dev.to](https://dev.to/devteam/native-share-to-dev-button-is-now-on-stack-overflow-3a5a) and not Stack Overflow.

In a nutshell: yes, this is an official partnership. The idea is to make DEV, a social blogging platform for developers, the place to have extended discussions about a Q&A's subject matter so as not to clutter up the main Q&A. Or just write anything about the Q&A, really, since sharing to DEV essentially just creates an embed with an excerpt of the Q&A in the post composer.

Comment: Is it intended to replace meta and chat?

Comment: @James: Not at all. Meta is for discussion of site policies revolving around a question, not the question's subject matter (i.e. discussing if the question is on-topic, not discussing the question's programming language or the problem being solved). Chat doesn't always have a specific question as a topic. This is one *more* place, if you will, to have offbeat freeform discussion that may or may not concern specific Q&As.

Comment: see also [official explanation at MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332816/165773)

Comment: Why DEV, why not Reddit?

Comment: @Div [redditors have got their notice already](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258877/839601) :)

Comment: Seems like missing the mark by a wide margin. Chat created by specific Q&A is already fine, and could be very nice with a bit of spit and polish applied to it.

Comment: @TylerH: Yeah, I don't know why they promote the extended discussion aspect so much. The ability to supplement your own thoughts, lessons, etc to the existing Q&A in a full blog post with a cool embed (what sort of flashy stuff is apparently what the site is all about), and getting wider exposure (at least via social media) on a centralized site, while not cluttering up the Q&A itself on here should be the much bigger draw IMO. (I get that that counts as discussion in the most distilled sense of the word, but it's most likely not the sort of "discussion" most of us think of.)

Comment: This seems... superfluous when we already have chat which is already heavily underused (_citation needed_). Why push this sort of discussion off-site when we have the alternative of improving the tools we already have?

Comment: @Lewis maybe the goal is to drop said tools in the future and just point to these external resources *[citation needed]*. Saves having to update the other tools and they get some networking done too.

Comment: Because we really needed _more_ social media...

Comment: @Lundin I nominate you to be our top-influencer ...

Comment: @Script47 they don't update the other tools (chat) anyway and we get by just fine

Comment: @TimCastelijns yup.

Comment: "a social blogging platform for developers" because _of course_ that's a thing

Comment: @TimCastelijns Except all the pains that have been aired over the last, y'know, decade.

Comment: *["... 'Sign In with Twitter' ... 'Sign In with GitHub' ... We require social login to prevent abuse."](https://dev.to/enter)*. What?? Or were they just lazy implementing a login system? [Steve](https://www.grc.com/sqrl/sqrl.htm) [Gibson's SQRL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQRL) is a possibility.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: Yeah, I can't see how that would prevent abuse at all.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: I am more disturbed by the categorization of *Twitter* as chaotic good...

Comment: *["Stack Overflow = lawful evil. Twitter = chaotic good. DEV = lawful good. Hacker News = neutral evil. Reddit = chaotic neutral. GitHub = neutral good. Slashdot = lawful neutral](https://dev.to/devteam/native-share-to-dev-button-is-now-on-stack-overflow-3a5a)* (Katerina Borodina's comment). I don't know what the middle icon is (generic?). And the "/g/" thingy.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Reverse image search tells me the middle icon is https://codepen.io/ . /g/ is a 4chan board.

Comment: Uggh, for something called "dev.to", it looks very unprofessional, and there seems no way to use a more compact font or layout. And why only Twatter or GitHub?

Comment: Stack Overflow announcement regarding this partnership will be posted in 6 - 8 weeks.

Comment: @KenY-N, It's dev.to - I believe it is meant to look like it is in development - perhaps you want "prod.to" instead? (Although jokes aside I'm not a fan of the style either.)

Comment: It seems very similar to Medium. They probably hope to make money from gathering and hosting developer's "stories".

Comment: If you blog regularly, you're probably used to linking to SO answers because they form the path to solving a problem. So from that POV this makes sense. I syndicate some of my technical blog posts to DEV so I can see this being useful. I don't see it replacing any feature that SO has, it's just peripheral. As for your comment, @KenY-N , I think this is subjective... I find the look and feel of dev to be a breath of fresh air :) I trust the current team behind DEV, their culture, and intentions. They advocate and support hosting your own content and syndicating (@Bachsau). My 2c.

Comment: @Ste Griffiths hit the nail on the head. I'm considering doing the same with my own blog posts, just to get a little extra exposure.

Comment: What even is dev.to?